# Converter RTF to String através de SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-basic-6

Boas pessoal tenho um pequeno problema, foi-me pedido que se faça através de SQL converter um texto feito através de uma RichTextBox (VB 6) para string normal, mas é que esta RichTextBox também serve para por caracteres chineses e é aqui que o problema existe.

Já estou nisto a 2 dias, não consegui fazer isto através do SQL, tentei fazer uma DLL em C# para isto e adicionar ao SQL e criar um metodo no SQL para usar a DLL, mas não tenho acesso a Class RichTextBox que se encontra dentro de WinForms.dll (não da para adicionar ao SQL).

Como exemplo tenho este RTF:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang2070{\fonttbl{\f0\fmodern\fprq6\fcharset134 SimSun;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 MS Sans Serif;}}  \viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang2052\f0\fs17\'b7\'f2\'c8\'cb\'b7\'eb\'b7\'f2\'c8\'cb6346\'b8\'f6\'ba\'ec\'b5\'c4\'b9\'f0\'bb\'a8\lang2070\f1   \par }
```

que no qual deveria de dar

> 夫人冯夫人6346个红的桂花

Já aconselhei a ter-se um campo na tabela de SQL um para o RTF e outro para a string, não é ideal mas seria uma solução.

Será possivel converter isto atraves de uma DLL, sem ter acesso a class RichTextBox ?! Que se conseguise acesso a Class RichTextBox em DLL e a pudese adicionar ao servidor de SQL já estaria feito, mas infelizmente não consigo

Edit.
Depois de ler o que foi aconselhado, tentei a solução de PowerShell (visto ter acesso ao RichTextBox directamente) mas da-me sempre erro.

O codigo que estou a testar em SQL:

```
DECLARE 
@StringRTF VARCHAR(MAX),
@Posh VARCHAR(8000)


SET @StringRTF = (select traduçao from artigos where Cod_Art='01010066')
SET @Posh = 'powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; $Rtb = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox; $stringRTF = ''' + @StringRTF + '''; $Rtb.Rtf = $stringRTF; $Retorno = $Rtb.Text; Write-Host($Retorno);"'

EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @Posh
```

No qual da-me sempre este erro:

> The string is missing the terminator: '.
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx 
>      ception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

Mas se ao Criar um projecto em c# WinForms, ir a buscar a info a DB e passar para uma RichTextBox o texto aparece como deve ser sem problemas nenhuns.

```
string tempString = String.Empty;
using (var con = new SqlConnection(SQLString))
{
    con.Open();
    {
        using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select traduçao as tradu from artigos where Cod_Art='01010066'";
            using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                dr.Read();
                tempString = dr["tradu"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
this.RichTextBoxTest.Rtf = tempString;
string testString = this.RichTextBoxTest.Text;
```

BtW não percebo o de muito ampla, o problema é querer passar um RTF para String normal em SQL, no qual passei a info como deve ser, o exemplo do RTF e o que ele retorna se o por numa RichTextBox,pedi apenas ajuda para soluções para isto

Comment: Recomendo ler [este artigo.](https://www.dirceuresende.com/blog/sql-server-como-converter-uma-string-rtf-para-texto-remover-tags-rtf-utilizando-clr-csharp-ou-powershell/) Ele apresenta solução para este problema por meio de SQL CLR(Common Language Runtime) e por meio de Powershell, além das soluções comuns em C#.

Comment: Obrigada, a DLL que fala no artigo (RichTextStripper) retorna o que já tinha consegui a 2 dias através do SQL `·òÈË·ë·òÈË6346¸öºìµÄ¹ð»¨` vou tentar a solução do PowerShell como têm acesso a WinForms poderá ser que consiga fazer alguma coisa disto depois digo alguma coisa.

Comment: Ok, estou tentando compreender melhor este assunto também, mas compartilhei o artigo pois penso que poderia solucionar.

Comment: E agradeço :D tem lá a forma da PowerShell que me da acesso a WinForms AKA Ao RichTextBox e deverei de conseguir por ai

Comment: Sim, deveria existir uma solução mais simples para este tipo de situação.